# I having problem with disposing the current window in swing

Tags: java, swing

This is a java swing application
I need to dispose the the current window and navigate to another. But i when disposing the current window it does not dispose (exit) but new window opens. I have tried several things including initializing the frame in various ways and places. can someone help me? You can find the onclick method at the bottom of the code
I having same problem with every window.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class AddStudent extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField groupNo;
    private JTextField programme;
    private JTextField generatedGroupId;
    private JTextField generatedSubGroupId;
    private JTextField subGroup;
    **static AddStudent frame;**
    
    
    String sYear ="Y1",sSem="S2",sProgramme,sGroup,sSubGroup,sGroupId,sSubGroupId;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame = new AddStudent();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    /**
     * 
     */
    public AddStudent() {
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 575);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setForeground(new Color(153, 51, 255));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblYear = new JLabel("Programme");
        lblYear.setForeground(new Color(25, 25, 112));
        lblYear.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblYear.setBounds(453, 196, 100, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblYear);
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Year");
        label.setForeground(new Color(25, 25, 112));
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        label.setBounds(453, 119, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(label);
        
        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Semester");
        label_1.setForeground(new Color(25, 25, 112));
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        label_1.setBounds(453, 158, 100, 14);
        contentPane.add(label_1);
        
        JLabel lblGroupId = new JLabel("Generate Group ID");
        lblGroupId.setForeground(new Color(25, 25, 112));
        lblGroupId.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblGroupId.setBounds(453, 287, 156, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblGroupId);
        
        JLabel lblGroupNo = new JLabel("Group No");
        lblGroupNo.setForeground(new Color(25, 25, 112));
        lblGroupNo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblGroupNo.setBounds(453, 243, 100, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblGroupNo);
        
        JLabel lblSubGroupId = new JLabel("Sub Group No");
        lblSubGroupId.setForeground(new Color(25, 25, 112));
        lblSubGroupId.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblSubGroupId.setBounds(453, 335, 100, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblSubGroupId);
        
        JLabel lblGenerateSubGroup = new JLabel("Generate Sub Group ID");
        lblGenerateSubGroup.setForeground(new Color(25, 25, 112));
        lblGenerateSubGroup.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblGenerateSubGroup.setBounds(453, 382, 156, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblGenerateSubGroup);
        
        JLabel lblStudent = new JLabel("ADD STUDENT");
        lblStudent.setForeground(new Color(0, 51, 51));
        lblStudent.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        lblStudent.setBounds(403, 11, 206, 59);
        contentPane.add(lblStudent);
        
        JLabel image = new JLabel("");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/class1.png"));
        image.setIcon(img);
        image.setBounds(103, 119, 300, 300);
        contentPane.add(image);
        
        groupNo = new JTextField();
        groupNo.setBounds(651, 245, 199, 25);
        contentPane.add(groupNo);
        groupNo.setColumns(10);
        
        programme = new JTextField();
        programme.setText("");
        programme.setColumns(10);
        programme.setBounds(651, 198, 199, 25);
        contentPane.add(programme);
        
        String[] yearList = {"Y1","Y2","Y3","Y4"};
        
        JComboBox year = new JComboBox(yearList);
        year.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
                    sYear = (String)year.getSelectedItem();
                  
            }
            
        });
        year.setBounds(651, 111, 197, 25);
        contentPane.add(year);
        
        String[] semList = {"S1","S2"};
        JComboBox semester = new JComboBox(semList);
        semester.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                 sSem = (String)semester.getSelectedItem();
            }
            
            
        });
        semester.setBounds(651, 155, 197, 25);
        contentPane.add(semester);
        
        generatedGroupId = new JTextField();
        generatedGroupId.setEditable(false);
        generatedGroupId.setColumns(10);
        generatedGroupId.setBounds(651, 291, 199, 25);
        contentPane.add(generatedGroupId);
        
        generatedSubGroupId = new JTextField();
        generatedSubGroupId.setEditable(false);
        generatedSubGroupId.setColumns(10);
        generatedSubGroupId.setBounds(651, 382, 199, 25);
        contentPane.add(generatedSubGroupId);
        
        subGroup = new JTextField();
        subGroup.setColumns(10);
        subGroup.setBounds(651, 339, 199, 25);
        contentPane.add(subGroup);
        
        JButton btnGenerateGroupId = new JButton("Generate");
        btnGenerateGroupId.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        btnGenerateGroupId.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
                sGroup = groupNo.getText().toString();
                sSubGroup = subGroup.getText().toString();
                sProgramme = programme.getText().toString();
                
                if(sGroup.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Please Enter Group");
                }else if(sProgramme.isEmpty()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Please Enter Programme");
                }else {
                
                sGroupId = sYear + "." + sSem + "."+ sProgramme + "."+ sGroup;
                generatedGroupId.setText(sGroupId);
                
                }
            }
        });
        btnGenerateGroupId.setBackground(new Color(102, 51, 255));
        btnGenerateGroupId.setBounds(869, 292, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGenerateGroupId);
        
        JButton btnGenerateSubGroupId = new JButton("Generate");
        btnGenerateSubGroupId.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        btnGenerateSubGroupId.setBackground(new Color(102, 51, 255));
        btnGenerateSubGroupId.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                sGroup = groupNo.getText().toString();
                sSubGroup = subGroup.getText().toString();
                sProgramme = programme.getText().toString();
                
                if(sGroup.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Please Enter Group");
                }else if(sSubGroup.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Please Enter Sub Group");
                }else if(sProgramme.isEmpty()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Please Enter Programme");
                }else {
                    sSubGroupId = sYear + "." + sSem + "."+ sProgramme + "."+ sGroup + "." + sSubGroup;
                    generatedSubGroupId.setText(sSubGroupId);
                }
                
                
                
            }
        });
        btnGenerateSubGroupId.setBounds(869, 385, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGenerateSubGroupId);
        
        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        btnAdd.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        btnAdd.setBackground(new Color(102, 51, 255));
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                sGroup = groupNo.getText().toString();
                sSubGroup = subGroup.getText().toString();
                sProgramme = programme.getText().toString();
                
                if(sGroup.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Please Enter Group");
                }else if(sProgramme.isEmpty()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Please Enter Programme");
                }else {
                    
                    addDataConnection addDataConnection = new addDataConnection();
                    addDataConnection.insertStudent(sYear, sSem, sGroup, sSubGroup, sProgramme,sGroupId,sSubGroupId);
                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Group Added !");
                    
                    groupNo.setText("");
                    programme.setText("");
                    subGroup.setText("");
                    generatedSubGroupId.setText("");
                    groupNo.setText("");
                    generatedGroupId.setText("");
                    
                }
                
                
                
            }
        });
        btnAdd.setBounds(723, 436, 72, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnAdd);
        ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/home.png"));
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton(img1);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                StudentHome studentHome = new StudentHome();
                frame.dispose();
                studentHome.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        btnNewButton.setBounds(27, 11, 52, 48);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        
        JLabel lblHome = new JLabel("Home");
        lblHome.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 153));
        lblHome.setBounds(37, 70, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblHome);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Code works fine for me. I don't have access to the Student home class so I commented that out.Suggestions: 1) get rid of the static frame variable. There is not a proper usage of the static keyword and the variable is NOT needed. As suggested in the answer below your class "is a JFrame" so you can just invoke dispose(). 2) dispose the frame before creating and showing the next frame.

Comment: it works fine when runs one Frame alone but if i navigate from one to another again it will not get disposed. Can i use mulitiple jFrames is one applcation?

Comment: You can have multiple frames although you should NOT because an application should have a single frame. If you need a popup window then you should use a `modal JDialog`. Another option is to use a `CardLayout` and swap panels in your frame. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice/9554657#9554657.  In any case I gave you a couple of suggestions to try. If you need more help then post a proper [mre]. The demonstrate the concept all you need is a frame with a JButton. All the other componetns are irrelevant to your stated problem.

Comment: I think you should read the question before answering

Comment: (1-) I did. I even copy/pasted/compiled/tested the code. The frame will dispose() and the JVM will exit in the situation I described above. You should read/follow the suggestions. I can't test the situation you describe because you haven't poste an [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Windows class` has a method `dispose`.

`JFrame, extends Frame`, which in turn `extends Windows`. Your class `extends JFrame`, thus you have a direct access to `dispose()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but did not get. I have disposed suing jframe.dispose() but does not work

Comment: you dont need to use jframe.dispose(). simply invoke dispose(). it should work

Comment: Thank you you deserve a medal